# Powershell - check calendar permission

Tags: powershell

I tried to write a below code to check outlook calendar permission:

```
 $Usermailbox = Read-Host "Please enter the mailbox whose permissions you want to see"
      Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$Usermailbox :\calendar"
```

But when I tried to do that I got an error

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission: xxxx|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundExceptio
n|The specified mailbox Identity:“xxx ” doesn’t exist.
```

I know this is caused because the code sees $Usermailbox :\calendar as one string probably

How to separate those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a space in the between the mailbox and folder name. Since `:` is a valid variable name character, use `$()` to express the variable separately:

```sh
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($Usermailbox):\calendar"
```

Comment: Nice, but to disambiguate a stand-alone variable reference, `${Usermailbox}` is simpler.